# how can i replace the system function?

Tags: c, unix, client-server, system

code sample from server:

```
dup2( client, STDOUT_FILENO );  /* duplicate socket on stdout */
dup2( client, STDERR_FILENO );  /* duplicate socket on stderr too */

char * msgP = NULL;
int len = 0;
while (len == 0) {
    ioctl(client, FIONREAD, &len);
}

if (len > 0) {
    msgP = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    len = read(client, msgP, len);

    system(msgP);
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);
}
```

When I send a command from the client I call the system function. This function is sufficient for many commands but not for all. I tried several different commands and I had problems with a few (ex: nano). The problem I'm facing is that after I call the system function I can not send any input any more for that command (if necessary).I can still send other commands.
My question is how can I solve this problem?

P.S. i did some test and cd command also dont work . who can explain me why?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: **Read a lot more.** You should spend several weeks in reading more. Start by reading the documentation of *every* function you are using. Your question is not clear enough. Provide some [MCVE]. Read also a good Linux programming book, perhaps the old [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/).

Comment: StackOverflow is not a do-my-homework service. You are expected to do some research before asking here.

Comment: please format your question properly and correct the grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `test` and `cd` commands are built into command-line shells: The shells do not execute them as external programs. They read those commands and process them by making changes inside the shell program itself.

When you execute a program with `system` or a routine from the `exec` family, it creates a separate process that runs the program. A separate process can read input, write output, change files, and communicate on the network, but it cannot change things inside the process that created it (except that it can send some information to that process, by providing a status code when it exits or by various means of interprocess communication). This is why `cd` cannot be executed with `system`: A separate process cannot change the working directory of another process. In order to execute a `cd` command, you must call `chdir` or `fchdir` to change the working directory for your own process.

There is a separate `test` command, but some shells choose to implement it internally instead of using the external program. Regarding `nano`, I do not know why it is not working for you. It works for me when I use `system("nano")` or `system("nano xyz")`. You would have to provide more information about the specific problem you are seeing with `nano`.

The way that `ssh` provides remote command execution is that it executes a shell process on the server. A shell is a program that reads commands from its input and executes them. Some of the commands, like `cd`, it executes internally. Other commands it executes by calling external programs. To provide a similar service, you could either write your own shell or execute one of the existing shells. On Unix systems, standard shells may be found in `/bin` with names ending in `sh`, such as `/bin/bash` and `/bin/csh`. (Not everything ending in `sh` is necessarily a shell, though.)

Even if you execute a shell, there are a number of details to doing it properly, including:

- Ensuring that the standard input, standard output, and standard error streams of the shell are connected the way you want them to be.
- Passing the desired environment and command-line arguments to the shell.

Comment: 306/5000
thank you . was very useful. and how about the "nano" problem: I wanted to change a file from the client. using nano file I was able to open the editor and get the answer but I could not edit it anymore because any input I sent from the client was taken as a parameter for the system function.

Comment: now the only question i have is how can i send to stdin the string from msgP?